# Jquery, Pass values from id to another js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp-classic

I want to pass the values from one Jquery Function to another.

Running this function

```
        $(function() {
        $('#ProjectWHDate').change(function(){
$('#TaskFechHours').load('disabledtimes.asp?RobotID='?RobotID=1&ProjectWHDate=10/10/2020);

        });
    });
```

im getting from disabledtimes.asp this result:

```
'timeFormat': 'H:i', 'minTime': '9:00pm', 'maxTime': '17:00mm', 'showDuration': true, 'step': 15, 'disableTimeRanges':[['10:00', '13:00']]
```

So Far So Good...
But i want to pass this result to another script.
This one...

```
$(function() {
$('#ProjectWHDateStartHour<%=rsaddrobots("RobotsID")%>').timepicker({ 
//
Here i want  the result to be...
//
});
});
```

All i have done so far is get the results in this

```
<div id="TaskFechHours"></div>
```

Any Ideas???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The first thing I would do is test it without trying to add the ASP variable to the end of your `#ProjectWHDateStartHour` element identity. If you would like more help you will need to share more of your code so this is reproducable. For example what is `rsaddrobots()` and where is the `#ProjectWHDateStartHour` element in your HTML?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The rsaddrobots() is the recordset of all users, so i can find whos have free and when ours to work, ProjectWHDateStartHour  is an input text select form for timepicker.
I solve this by recreate the entire timepicker script inside div element. So every date form change i have new timepicker select form. Thanks again